# Does the const keyword matter when you pass arguments by value?

Tags: c++

Is there any difference when I write
    `void fun(const int index);`
and
    `void fun(int index);`
?

Also, is there any difference between

```
void fun(const std::vector<std::stack<int>> li);
```

and

```
void fun(std::vector<std::stack<int>> li);
```

?

As I'm passig the arguments by value, I'm confused about how useful is to put the const keyword here. It is a good practice to put it though?

Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: One clearly states that you will not change that variable, even if it is local.

Comment: Remember that one does not use `const` because it is *good practice*. One uses `const` to clearly communicate to the caller whether or not the function or method will modify the provided object. What *is* a good practice is to think about such things during the design stage: do I want to modify the provided object? Yes: do not use `const`; No: use `const`. Finally, notice that when you pass by value what you are really doing is creating a copy of the element (as opposed to passing a reference, where the actual object is passed with no copies involved).

Answer (score 4):

> `void fun(const int index);` and `void fun(int index);`

It makes no difference in the declaration (or to the caller). The difference it makes in the function definition is what you'd expect, the parameter is a `const` object.

> `void fun(const std::vector<std::stack<int>> li);` and `void fun(std::vector<std::stack<int>> li);`

Same thing.

> It is a good practice to put it though?

You should mark function parameters passed by value `const` under the same circumstances that you would mark a local variable `const`: you don't need to modify it, and you want to be sure that you don't accidentally pass it (by reference or pointer) to some function that modifies it.

If you do use it, it is a detail of the implementation of the function, it is not part of the function's interface. So you should leave it out of the declaration. Unless, perhaps, you are using tools that don't understand C++ properly (like text search) and you want the declaration and the definition to match exactly for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function:

```
void func(const int index)
{
...
}
```

You are stating that you will not change the value of index in your function.  Thus, if you want to manipulate it, you'd have to make another copy of it.  For example,  lets say you wanted to double the value of `i` save it in a vector and then return it:

```
int func(const int i)
{
    int newi = i * 2;
    v.push_back(newi);
    return newi;
}
```

or

```
int func(int i)
{
    i *= 2;
    v.push_back(i);
    return i;
}
```

In the first version, you are forced to make 2 copies of `i` (on as the function argument, and the other to manipulate).  In the second version, you only have 1 copy of `i`.

NOTE:  In this simple example, the additional copies may be elided, but that is not always the case with more complicated constructs.